# when did SQL Server get uniqueidentifiers as a datatype?

Tags: sql-server

Who remembers when Microsoft Sql Server got UniqueIdentifier as a data type.  I'm guessing it was 7.0 but maybe it was as early as 6.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 7.0 introduced UniqueIdentifier as I remember.

Answer (score -2):

They were introduced in SQL Server 2000. See the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985066.aspx

Comment: It was 7.0. Quote from that article: "SQL Server 7.0 introduced a whole range of Unicode data types and the GUID unique identifier..."